# Run Python function in few thread with while

Tags: python, multithreading, python-asyncio

I'm a bit noob in concurrent Python execution. 
Idea is to run function `create_user` in several threads, to spend less time.
I think about `threading` or `asyncio` modules. I tried to do it on my own, but I lost in global scope and return methods...

````
def create_users(users):
    users_list = []
    users_to_create = conc - users
    while len(users_list) < users_to_create:
        user = api.create_user()
        users_list.append(user)
    return users_list```
````

Comment: if *create_user* does not require  CPU time there is no interest at all to do them in separated threads/process. Else you can use multiprocessing Pool for instance. Why with *while* ?

Comment: `api.create_user()` Are you making your own http requests? Or did you import a module and are calling functions? Also which api are u consuming?

Comment: Yep, this is method with simple POST request to create user.
I use while because this is my implementation to create necessary count of user. While number of users is less - create user.

Comment: @SergeyMoroz did you see my answer ? of course I defined the function *create_user* to return something printable for the test but that function can do `return api.create_user()` or anything else

Answer (score 2):

if *create_user* does not require CPU time there is no interest at all to do them in separated threads/process. Else you can use *multiprocessing Pool*, for instance:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count

def create_user(rank):
    return "I am user {}".format(rank) # return api.create_user()

def create_users(users):
   nb_process = cpu_count()
   with Pool(nb_process) as pool:
      users_list = list(pool.imap(create_user, range(1,users))) # range(0, conc - users)
   return users_list

print(create_users(50))
```

execution:

```
% python3 p.py
['I am user 1', 'I am user 2', 'I am user 3', 'I am user 4', 'I am user 5', 'I am user 6', 'I am user 7', 'I am user 8', 'I am user 9', 'I am user 10', 'I am user 11', 'I am user 12', 'I am user 13', 'I am user 14', 'I am user 15', 'I am user 16', 'I am user 17', 'I am user 18', 'I am user 19', 'I am user 20', 'I am user 21', 'I am user 22', 'I am user 23', 'I am user 24', 'I am user 25', 'I am user 26', 'I am user 27', 'I am user 28', 'I am user 29', 'I am user 30', 'I am user 31', 'I am user 32', 'I am user 33', 'I am user 34', 'I am user 35', 'I am user 36', 'I am user 37', 'I am user 38', 'I am user 39', 'I am user 40', 'I am user 41', 'I am user 42', 'I am user 43', 'I am user 44', 'I am user 45', 'I am user 46', 'I am user 47', 'I am user 48', 'I am user 49']
%
```

here of course there is no interest to do in multiprocessing